# Solving $\cos(\log_{4x}(x+1))-\cos(\log_{4x}(4-x))\lt\log_{4x}(4-x)-\log_{4x}(x+1)$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, logarithms

There is an interesting inequality I've stumbled upon on the Internet. It has logarithms and trigonometry, but in contrast to something like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1029060/inequality-with-a-mixture-of-logs-and-trig) that uses trigonometry and logarithms separately, this one takes such kind of inequality to a whole new level!

See for yourself. The task is to solve the following inequality over reals:

$$\cos(\log_{4x}(x+1))-\cos(\log_{4x}(4-x))\lt\log_{4x}(4-x)-\log_{4x}(x+1)$$

I've found the domain of the inequality by applying restrictions to real-valued logarithms: its base must not be neither zero nor one, and its argument must be positive.

$\begin{cases}4x\gt0,\\4x\neq1,\\4-x\gt0,\\x+1\gt0.\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow\begin{cases}x\gt0,\\x\neq0.25,\\x\lt4,\\x\gt-1.\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow x\in(0;0.25)\cup(0.25;4)$

I tried to use the fact that the difference of cosines has the domain $[-2;2]$ no matter the arguments of the cosines. My assumption comes from the following facts:

- The domain of $\cos(x)$ is $[-1;1]$.
- The smaller the subtrahend, the bigger the difference.
- The bigger the subtrahend, the smaller the difference.

Thus, the domain of $\cos(a)-\cos(b)$ is $[\min(\cos(a))-\max(\cos(b));\max(\cos(a))-\min(\cos(b))]=[-1-1;1-(-1)]=[-2;2]$. QED.

This did not work, however, because the right hand side sadly isn't always greater than two.

From a mere observation, if we let $u=\log_{4x}(x+1)$, $v=\log_{4x}(4-x)$, and $f(x)=cos(x)$, then the inequality becomes $f(u)-f(v)\lt v-u$, leading to the inequality $f(u)+u\lt f(v)+v$. This may be useful in some way, I guess.

I've also tried to step away from arbitrary logs and only use natural ones:
$$\cos\left(\dfrac{\log (x+1)}{\log (4x)}\right)-\cos\left(\dfrac{\log (4-x)}{\log (4x)}\right)\lt\dfrac{\log (4-x)-\log(x+1)}{\log (4x)}$$

...and I'm stuck here. No way to manipulate those cosines of which I'm aware.

So, how to approach this kind of inequalities properly?

Comment: Just saying, I didn't mean that any difference of cosines has exactly the domain $[-2;2]$; I just assumed that *any* difference of cosines will not exceed that domain and will have *up to* $[-2;2]$.

Comment: I think that this holds for $\frac 14 < x < \frac \pi 2-\epsilon$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici In other words, $x\in\left(\frac14;\frac{\pi}2\right)$?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici : $ x\in\left(\frac14;\frac32\right) $

Comment: @Narasimham. You are totally correct which implies that I am stupid. Cheers

Comment: It was hindsight only after plotting the $(f,g) !$

Comment: @Narasimham What if I'm not having an ability to plot full $(f,g)$ graph? Am I supposed to use some function properties?

Comment: We can also evaluate and check inequality by computing small values added/removed near the roots / zeros.

Answer (score 1):

By inspection of log arguments the crucial roots/critical points of equality  are noted at:

$$ x= (0,\frac14,\frac32,4)$$

We compare the two component functions $ f(x),g(x)$ ( blue,red) defined/ listed in Mathematica, intervals are determined by above end points.

By evaluating the function signs in the neighborhood of the roots ( it suffices to track function behaviour) it is found :

In the interval $(\frac14,\frac32)\; f(x)< g(x) $.

Outside this full interval  $ f(x) , g(x) $ define all intervals of inequality. The plot also confirms the intervals.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\cos a - \cos b = -2\sin\dfrac{a+b}{2}\sin\dfrac{a-b}{2}$$

Comment: I know the formula but factorising the difference of cosines doesn't seem to give much clarity to the problem.